# Import bootstrap to react Atom?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, atom-editor

I have successfully imported Jquery to atom using the following code:

**import $ from 'jquery';**

What would be the equivalent for importing css-bootstrap?

*NOTE:*
I have successfully installed bootstrap into my project folder (using the command line):

**$ npm install react-bootstrap --save**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally just import regular bootstrap using

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
```

Then call it in my app like

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

I would also recommend using atom [autocomplete-modules](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-modules) package to help finding your desired files in modules

Keep in mind that it will work if you are using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-stylesheet) to help import assets in JavaScript

Comment: tnx fo autocomplete-modules.

Answer (score 1):

You could use bootstrap's CDN (taken from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html):

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of
>   Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included css. However, some
>   stylesheet is required to use these components. How and which
>   bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the simplest way is to
>   include the latest styles from the CDN.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

Or you could try by installing regular bootstrap module:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
```

and adding the following line to your `client.js` (make sure you set your path correct):

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Comment: The problems is that in my dist folder there are only .js files, there isn't any css folder wich then spreads to .css file

Comment: In that case first option is ideal, have you tried it?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by the first option, are you referring to <link rel, referencing  css.

Comment: Yes correct, since it doesn't ship with any css, by using the CDN you are able to use it's features as stated in the link.